# Sudoku Solving help IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a Sudoku solver for a course I am in, I can get it to read a text file that is laid out like this.

```
003020600
900305001
001806400
008102900
700000008
006708200
002609500
800203009
005010300
```

however, I cannot get it to read a file like this and it absolutely needs to be able to.

```
003020600
900305001
001806400
008102900
700000008
006708200
002609500
800203009
005010300

000900800
128006400
070800060
800430007
500000009
600079008
090004010
003600284
001007000

000000000
079050180
800000007
007306800
450708096
003502700
700000005
016030420
000000000

000020040
008035000
000070602
031046970
200000000
000501203
049000730
000000010
800004000
```

When I attempt to run the code I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SudokuSolver.py", line 76, in <module>
    print_board(pr)
  File "SudokuSolver.py", line 61, in print_board
    output += (str(pr[x][y]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Source Code:

```
import sys

board = []
with open('puzzles.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
         board.append(list(map(int,line.strip())))

#backtracking
def solve(pr):
    find = find_empty(pr)
    if not find:
        return True
    else:
        row, col = find

    for r in range(1,10):
        if valid(pr, r, (row, col)):
            pr[row][col] = r

            if solve(pr):
                return True

            pr[row][col] = 0

    return False

def valid(pr, num, pos):
    # Check row
    for r in range(len(pr[0])):
        if pr[pos[0]][r] == num and pos[1] != r:
            return False

    # Check column
    for r in range(len(pr)):
        if pr[r][pos[1]] == num and pos[0] != r:
            return False

    # Check box
    box_x = pos[1] // 3
    box_y = pos[0] // 3

    for r in range(box_y*3, box_y*3 + 3):
        for c in range(box_x * 3, box_x*3 + 3):
            if pr[r][c] == num and (r,c) != pos:
                return False

    return True

#formatting
def print_board(pr):
  output = ''

  with open("puzzleoutput.txt", "a") as file:
    for x in range(len(pr)):
        if x % 3 == 0 and x != 0:
            output += (str("\n - - -   - - -   - - - "))
        for y in range(len(pr[0])):
          if y % 3 == 0 and y != 0:
            output += (str(" | "))
          if y == 8:
            output += (str(pr[x][y]))
          else: 
            output += (str("f{board[x][y]} "))

    file.write(str(output))
    return  

def find_empty(pr):
    for r in range(len(pr)):
        for c in range(len(pr[0])):
            if pr[r][c] == 0:
                return (r, c)  # row, col

    return None

print_board(board)
solve(board)
```

I have tried numerous things, and I can usually get it to stop giving me errors, however, it doesn't print the solved puzzles into the text document, and I need it to do so in a specific way.

This is the last attempt I tried:

```
with open('puzzles.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

Comment: Your code is designed to only solve one board. You should at least try to detect the empty line. Can you do that? Then at an empty line solve the board, print the result, and reset the board, and continue the file reading loop. Can you do that?

Comment: You are using the `board` variable in your printing function, but you named it `pr` in the declaration.

Comment: even with board changed to pr it still gives the error.

Comment: When you see an error, you need to think why you might be receiving this error. _List index out of range_? What list and index? `pr[x][y]`. Could `pr[x]` not have a `[y]` index? I wonder if I could print something out to test. Maybe `len(pr[x])`? Yikes! `pr[x]` is empty? I wonder which line in my input could be causing an empty list in `board`. Could it be that empty line between boards? How do I detect and handle this situation?

Comment: I am still stuck. Don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try checking for empty spaces as one of the comments suggested:

```
board = []
with open('puzzles.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
         if(line == " "):
            continue
         else:
            board.append(list(map(int,line.strip())))
```

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately still getting that error.

Comment: Try printing the lines to see what the string literals are for the empty spaces. such as print repr(line). This will print a string with the quotes to see if the empty spaces are ""(empty) or "                "(bunch of spaces in between which won't return as empty). You can also do what the other comments are saying to print pr[x][y] to see what's going on.

Comment: Still having the issues, I have tried everything I can think of.

Comment: You can also check if the string contains numbers so ` if(line.isdigit()):
            board.append(list(map(int,line.strip())))
         else:
            continue`   isdigit() will return True if all characters in the string can be a digit.

Comment: I've managed to find out that as it goes to read the next set of puzzles that's when the error seems to trigger, I took a step back to just produce the results in the console instead of a file, and it does the first puzzle perfectly fine, but when it goes to the next set it gives me the IndexError: list index out of range error